# How to get everything rounded in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, graphics

I was watching [a video on tkinter basics etc.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mop6g-c5HEY)  and with the exact same code that's shown in the first 10m he has everything rounded but mine are square. Does anyone know how he gets this because I would really like rounded objects.

Searched a bit but didn't find anything.

Comment: Did you use `ttk.Button` also on what platform you are operating?

Comment: I did use ttk button. But in the video its also the frame and the input fields that are rounded. Im using windows 10

Comment: Its normally OS dependent what is shown, to get you a "native look". You can look into styling on the every same tutorial, it's marked on hour 9.